# What is the proper way to add retry loop to VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access, vba7

In the following code, we occasionally get collision errors. If it would wait a second and retry, it would go through.

I want it to try once. If it fails, log the error and retry. If it fails 3 times, MsgBox to the user, give up and return. The only way I can think of is using a GOTO back to the ExeHandler. Seems there should be a better way.

```
  Public Function RunADO(strContext As String, strSQL As String, Optional intErrSilent As Integer = 0, Optional intErrLog = -1) As Integer
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  ExeHandler:

     PostToLog strContext, "SQL: " & strSQL
     CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
     RunADO = -1
     Exit Function
  ErrHandler:
     RunADO = 0
     If intErrSilent = 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Run ADO"
     End If
     If intErrLog = -1 Then
        PostErrorToLog Err.Number, strContext, Err.Source & ":" & Err.Description & ": " & "SQL: " & strSQL
     End If
  End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this...

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Const MaxRetries As Long = 3

    Public Function RunADO(strContext As String, strSQL As String, Optional intErrSilent As Integer = 0, Optional intErrLog = -1) As Integer
        Dim attemptCounter As Long
        For attemptCounter = 1 To MaxRetries
            RunADO = RunADOInternal(strContext, strSQL, intErrSilent, intErrLog)
            If RunADO = -1 Then
                Exit Function
            End If
            If intErrSilent = 0 And attemptCounter >= MaxRetries Then
                MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Run ADO"
                RunADO = 0
                Exit Function
            End If
            If intErrLog = -1 Then
                PostErrorToLog Err.Number, strContext, Err.Source & ":" & Err.Description & ": " & "SQL: " & strSQL
            End If
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next attemptCounter
    End Function

    Private Function RunADOInternal(strContext As String, strSQL As String, Optional intErrSilent As Integer = 0, Optional intErrLog = -1) As Integer
      On Error GoTo ErrHandler

         PostToLog strContext, "SQL: " & strSQL
         CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
         RunADO = -1
         Exit Function
    ErrHandler:
         RunADO = 0
    End Function
```

Comment: These are both excellent answers. I like this one a bit better as I think it is clearer and easier to read. Separating the execution into it's own function allows you to use the built in error handling and still wrap logic around it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a Do / Loop statement that ends when the maximum number of attempts have been made.

```
Public Function RunADO(strContext As String, _
                       strSQL As String, _
                       Optional intErrSilent As Integer, _
                       Optional intErrLog = -1) As Integer
  
    Dim Attempts As Integer
    
    Do While Attempts < 3
        On Error Resume Next
        PostToLog strContext, "SQL: " & strSQL
        CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        If Err.Number Then
            If intErrSilent = 0 Then
               MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Run ADO"
            End If
            If intErrLog = -1 Then
               PostErrorToLog Err.Number, strContext, _
                              Err.Source & ":" & Err.Description & ": " & "SQL: " & strSQL
            End If
            Attempts = Attempts + 1
        Else
            RunADO = -1
            Exit Do
        End If
     Loop
  End Function
```